# Android Zoom Controls keep zooming in and will not stop

Tags: android, widget, zooming

My zoom controls keep zooming in when I press the button, and will not stop, am I missing something?

```
zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoom);
        zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        mc.zoomIn();
                }
        });
        zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        mc.zoomOut();
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking an educated guess that `mc` is a `MapController`, perhaps calling `zoomIn()` on a `MapController` triggers the relevant `OnClickListener` as well. Try logging every time you are in your `onClick()` to see if you get a chain of log messages. If so, then you probably can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but if I just want it to have the zoom controls appear and make them usable do I need to anything other 

map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
map.displayZoomControls(true);
?

Comment: No, that will suffice. And the second statement is only needed if you want to programmatically make them appear -- if your map is clickable, then users will cause the zoom controls to pop up when they tap near the bottom of the screen.